# Rust feature flag for functon parameters

Tags: rust

Is there a way to apply Rust's feature flag support to function parameters? I have a function which takes bunch of inputs, but one of the inputs should only be passed if a feature is active. Of course I can make that parameter optional like:

```
pub fn my_function(input1: usize, input2: String, input3: Option<Vec<u32>>) -> () {...}
```

But is there a way to instead make use of the feature flag and define something like this?:

```
pub fn my_function(
    input1: usize,
    input2: String,
    #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
    input3: Vec<u32>
) -> () {...}
```

Similarly, later calling it as: `my_function(0, "", #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")] vec![0])`?

Comment: The natural implementation [just works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd4b21767a08a30c3eb2effffee7873a)?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thanks, but does not seem to work for return values `pub fn my_function() -> (usize, #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")] usize)`.

Comment: So do you want return values or parameters?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Both would be nicest. Trying to figure out what I need to specify as `Option<...>` and what not.

Comment: You can use a type alias for the return type ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f7993292fa07bab510e1981c45cd6c76))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rust's feature flags are a thin wrapper around conditional compilation. Imagine how you'd write your code if the feature were always enabled, then again if it were always disabled, and wrap the lines that differ between the two with `#[cfg(..])` expressions. To define a function that differs, you can define two different versions and have them call a shared inner block if they're nearly the same, or just define them separately if they should do different things:

```rust
struct Thing;

impl Thing {
    #[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
    pub fn my_function(input1: usize, input2: String) {
        Thing::my_function_inner(input1, input2, None);
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
    pub fn my_function(input1: usize, input2: String, input3: Vec<u32>) {
        Thing::my_function_inner(input1, input2, Some(input3));
    }

    #[inline]
    fn my_function_inner(input1: usize, input2: String, input3: Option<Vec<u32>>) {
        todo!();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply tag the conditional argument with a `cfg` expression and use conditional compilation within the function body:

```rust
impl Thing {
  pub fn my_function(
    input1: usize,
    input2: String,
    #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")] input3: Vec<u32>,
  ) {
    // common implementation

    #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
    { /* `input3` is only available when feature is enabled */ }

    #[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
    { /* only run when feature is disabled */ }
  }
}
```

Choose whichever makes the most sense for your use case. The compiler will likely optimize them similarly.

To call this, you can either rely on the feature flag always being enabled/disabled and just use the corresponding version, or you can include code for both like so:

```rust
fn main() {
    #[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
    Thing::my_function(0, "".to_string());

    #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
    Thing::my_function(0, "".to_string(), vec![0]);
}
```

**EDIT:** To support conditionally compiled return types, you can declare your return type to be a `type` alias that is itself conditionally compiled, like so:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "my-feature")]
type ReturnType = (usize, usize);

#[cfg(not(feature = "my-feature"))]
type ReturnType = (usize,);

fn my_function() -> ReturnType { todo!() }
```

Thanks to @ChayimFriedman and @Jmb.

Comment: But how about for return values? It seems I cannot define a function as `pub fn my_function() -> (usize, #[cfg(feature = "my-feature")] usize)`.

Comment: Rust syntax requires that a function return type be a literal type; `cfg` expressions are not allowed in that position. I've updated my answer with the pattern to use for conditionally compiled return types.